# How to prevent two masters from being active at the same time when doing master election with a registry like Zookeeper, Consul, or etcd?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability, failover, etcd, consul

### tl;dr

Even if you implement master election with one of the registries such as Zookeeper, Consul, or etcd, there always seems to be a race condition where an old master does not realize it is no longer master and tries to write, while a new master is unblocked from writing, resulting in two instances of the service writing at the same time, which we want to avoid. How can we implement master election without this race condition?

### Detailed problem statement

Suppose we want to implement master election for failover using one of the registries such as Zookeeper, Consul, or etcd.

Suppose there are three instances of the service S1, S2, S3, each one with a corresponding registry node on the same machine, and currently S1 is master and S2 and S3 are slaves.

Furthermore, S1, S2, S3 all store shared state in the registry, but we do not want to have multiple instances write that state at the same time because concurrent access might make the state inconsistent.

Suppose S1 is in the middle of write operations to the shared state stored in the registry. That is, it will execute more write operations before checking again whether it is leader.

Suppose there is a network partition at this point. On one partition is S1. On the other partition is S2 and S3, so it has the quorum.

The registry correctly identifies S2 as the new leader and invalidates S1 as the leader.

S2 activates because it is the new leader and begins a series of write operations to the shared state stored in the registry.

The partition is healed.

At this point both S1 and S2 will execute write operations to the registry concurrently and both their write operations will succeed since the partition is healed, which might result in inconsistent state.

The sample trace is:

1. S1 is notified it is master, and begins write operations to shared state in registry
2. Partition happens, with S1 in one partition, S2 & S3 in the other
3. S2 is identified as new master
4. S2 is notified it is new master, and begins write operations to shared state in registry
5. Partition is repaired
6. S1 writes to shared state in registry and succeeds since no partition
7. S2 writes to shared state in registry and succeeds also, causing arbitrary interleaving of writes with S1
8. S1 is notified it is no longer master and stops writing

## Thoughts

- Thinking in terms of Consul's sessions, would an API write call that also takes a session ID and only succeeds if that session ID is still master's solve this problem?
- Is there such a call in Consul or one of the other registries?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies between steps 5 & 6. S1 shouldn't attempt to write immediately after healing the partition since it should have lost its leadership status during the partition.

S1 should be aware of this since it would have to re-establish connectivity to zookeeper.

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection has a description of the basic process. I'd look at Apache Curator for an implementation.

Or for something non-zookeeper this could happen via timeout values.

https://github.com/Netflix/edda/blob/48de14fc185d8b2d8605c51630c0906c7e923925/src/main/scala/com/netflix/edda/aws/DynamoDBElector.scala has a nice implementation of that approach.

I haven't tried to use Consul for this yet, but I suspect it should fall into one of these two categories.